# Setting log^2 Scale for Matlab Figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, scaling, axes

I have a plot of some data that I believe *should* be approximate `log^2(n) = log(n)^2`. I want to plot `n` on the horizontal axis and the data on the vertical axis, but I want to scale the horizontal axis by `log^2` so that I get approximately a straight line. Now, I know how to do this with just `log` instead of `log^2` (eg, use `semilogx`), but I don't know how to do it for `log^2`.

I tried doing set(gca,'xscale','log') to give `log` scaling, and then running the same thing again, hoping that this would rescale by `log` again. Unfortunately it didn't. (I believe) the only options for `'xscale'` are `linear` and `log`.

I've had a look around the usual forums (via a Google search), but I can't find the solution. There's lots on the question of just `log` scaling, and there's some on changing the base of the logarithm (not what I want to do). Any advice on this matter would be most appreciated! Thanks

---

Let me just add a clarification. In probability theory (which is what I do), it's common to write `log^2(n)` for `log(n)^2`. You talk about a mixing time being "log squared"; so this notation means that you can drop the `n` and still say `~ log^2`. So I believe my data is approximate `log(n)^2`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your are right about the `xscale` options. These are regular axes to use in plots. If you want your data to show up as a straight line, change your data in stead by taking `log` of your x-values, when you plot. Just remember to change `xlabel` accordingly to show what you have done.

E.g.

```
plot([1,10,100],[3,2,1])
set(gca,'xscale','log')
xlabel('x')
```

can be shown as

```
plot(log10([1,10,100]),[3,2,1])
xlabel('log10(x)')
```

EDIT:
You can alter `XTick` and `XTickLabel` manually like this in stead

```
set(gca,'XTick',log10(x))
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'10^0','10^1','10^2'})
```

Comment: Yeah, this is all I'd manage to come up with. The issue is that then the values on my horizontal axis are incorrect: the numbers they show are `log^2(n)` instead of `n`. Thanks anyway

Comment: (Also, see my note on what `log^2` means. I think you misunderstood (my ambiguous writing), so I've added clarification.)

Comment: I assumed u meant log(log(n)), but used the simpler example. If you care about the numbers shown, try looking at ([link]https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html)

Comment: I added a way you can manually change the axis ticks and ticklabels. This is not as flexible, but will get the work done if your care about the axes being pretty. (https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92565-how-do-i-control-axis-tick-labels-limits-and-axes-tick-locations)

Comment: Ok, thanks very much. I think that's the best I'm going to e able to do. I'll leave the question open a bit longer in case someone has some further insight! :)